# ADODB.Connection VB6: Error -2147023878 Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion

Tags: vb6, scheduled-tasks

Main Error Message:

```
ADODB.Connection VB6: Error -2147023878 Illegal operation attempted on a registry key 
that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)
```

How it happened?

We have a Task scheduler running a process that calls the exe file to get data from MSSQL server and writes it to a file.

The exe file is based on VB code.

On Googling, I am seeing related issues for SharePoint stuff. But there is no SharePoint in use here when get the error.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Note: No IIS is used. only Task scheduler and exe file.

From Event Viewer, just before the error pops up I see the below issue...

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
> applications or services.  The file will be unloaded now. The
> applications or services that hold your registry file  may not
> function properly afterwards.
>
> DETAIL -    14 user registry handles leaked from `\Registry\User\S-1-5-2............`

Comment: Is that machine perhaps shutting down while the program is running? I _seem_ to remember that this event happens at/right before Windows shutdown.